# Question regards firebase restrictions to api key

Tags: firebase, postman, api-key

I set up restrictions to my Firebase api key so that only my website and localhost can access to Firebase services but I've got a question.

Let's say that for testing purposes I want to call an endpoint from Postman, how can I setup restrictions so that I can call Cloud functions from postman?

Everything works from localhost and the website but when I try to call an endpoint from Postman it gives me this error:

```
{
    "message": "Firebase: Error (auth/requests-from-referer-<empty>-are-blocked.)."
}
```

Ok apparantly only few routes work, the login gives me no errors meanwhile the signup route gives me the same error you see above, I don't know why...I set up restrictions such every subroute of my site can access the Firebase products

Comment: The message hints that it needs the `Referer` header. Try to configure the Postman request so that it includes the `Referer` header and set it to a value allowed by configuration (something like `http://localhost` or `https://localhost` I guess, try tweaking it a bit)

Comment: Hi, it doesn't seem to work anyway

Comment: Any help would be highly appreciated